# Django - how to copy one, specific model instance between two databases

Tags: django

I have an application that has a model called CalculationResults. I also have two databases with the same scheme - let's call them "source" and "target". On source database, I have a specific instance of CalculationResults that I want to migrate to "target" database - preferably, I also want to change the field "owner" of this instance in the process. What is the easiest way to achieve this goal? The data I'm talking about is not huge, so it's rather a question of manpower vs computational power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done this, but I believe that following will work:

```
results = CalculationResults.objects.using('source').filter(field=search_field)

for result in results:
    result.owner = 'new owner'
    result.save(using='target')
```

Comment: So I just need to specify 'source' and 'target' in my settings.py and perform those commands in manage.py shell?

Comment: @Nephie yes. You will need though to import the necessary model: `from myapp.models import CalculationResults` and then execute the snippet I mentioned. You can see more details here: https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelmultidatabases.html

Comment: I had to write a custom routing function to allow relations between databases, but I've managed to copy the record successfully. Thank you!